# Put object in x,y position JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, coordinates, layout-manager

I'm trying to do something in Java, where I simply place an object at a specific `x, y` coordinates on a `JFrame`. I need to know what layout to use, or what I need to do to do this.. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: What should happen when the frame is resized?  Should the component expand?  What should happen when the frame is shrunk smaller than can display the component - should it truncate it, show a scroll-bar, hide it..?  Are the 'specific co-ordinates' relative to the top-left of the frame?

Answer (score 5):

You would do this with a `null` layout and then call setLocation or setBounds on the component. But you shouldn't be doing this in general as this makes for *very* inflexible GUI's that look good on one platform and terrible on another and that are *very* difficult to update and maintain. Just don't do this.

Comment: *"Just don't do this."*  There is always the option of "just don't mention this" which I think is preferable when it does not solve the problem in a realistic or real world way.

Comment: Well, The frame will not be re-sizable, and will only have one component.

Comment: @thefiscster510: "doesn't seem to work" doesn't give us enough information to be able to give detailed help. Consider editing your original post and adding compilable runnable code that shows us your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3):

[image: Component at Specific Co-ords]

This example provides 'white space' (or in this case 'green space') using an empty border.  Of course, all this 'specific co-ordinates' becomes more complicated if there are other components in the frame, but the same technique can be used to provide white space to particular components.

Note that it is usually best to wrap the component in a panel when providing white space, to preserve the existing border(s) of the component.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

class SpecificCoords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int specificX = 40;
        final int specificY = 20;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // imagine this is our 'frame'
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
                JPanel borderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                borderPanel.add(tf);
                borderPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(
                        specificX, specificY, 
                        specificX, specificY));
                borderPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                gui.add(borderPanel);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```